# Connect Azure App Service and Azure SQL VM

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sql-server

I have a setup where the connection string of my .NET application is configured at the app service level and the database used in it is present in an Azure SQL VM

I see the following error, while accessing my Web APIs in the app service

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - **Access is denied**.*

However, I’m able to connect to the database directly on my local system using SSMS with my organisation’s VPN

I’m struggling to find the right resource, appreciate if you someone can help me with steps to fix it

i just have the beginner level knowledge on Azure platform

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the same error like below.***

[image]

To resolve this issue I have removed private access and tried and then added new private access its work successfully.

Check the public access in selected network with firewall rule and allow exception as below.

[image]

And, when I remove this private endpoint and try to add new private access i can able to connect with my SQL server.

[image]

Check this connectivity as below.

[image]

My `azuresql,database server` connected successfully.

[image]

***Note***: *This error may occur in multiple ways if   are not **enable sql services** and in **tcp/Ip** If any of the protocols are **disabled** or if **Remote Connection Permission is disable** error may occur for this please refer the below documents.*

***Reference***:

[Microsoft SQL Server Error 2 Cannot Connect to Local: How to Solve? (systoolsgroup.com)](https://www.systoolsgroup.com/updates/microsoft-sql-server-error-2/)

[Resolving could not open a connection to SQL Server errors (mssqltips.com)](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2340/resolving-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-errors/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my database is present in a SQL Virtual Machine

Comment: Please check the above reference